# Modular arithmetic sum with diagram

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, power-series

> Steve places a counter at $0$ on [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M80EQ.png). On his first move, he moves the counter $1^1$ step clockwise to $1$. On his second move, he moves the counter $2^2$ steps clockwise to $5$. On his third move, he moves the counter $3^3$ steps clockwise to $2$. He continues in this manner, moving $n^n$ steps clockwise on his $n$th move. At which position will his counter be after $1234$ moves?

Comment: So mathematically, we're asked to find the last digit of
$$
1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \ldots + {1234}^{1234}
$$

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using modulo, but that didn't work

Comment: Define u(n) to be the units digit of the positive integer n (for example, u(25) = 5). Then look at the patterns of the powers. You will then need to sum the steps to get the final answer.

Comment: could you explain further? I haven't done functions yet.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BPowerMod%5Bn%2Cn%2C10%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C1234%7D%5D

The last digit is 7

Answer (score 0):

Let $a(n)=(1^1+2^2+...+n^n)\pmod{10}$

Note if $n\equiv m\pmod{100}$ then $a(n)\equiv a(m)\pmod{10}$

Implies $a(34)\equiv a(1234) \equiv 7\pmod{10}$

So answer is $7$

Sequence: https://oeis.org/A185353

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm still trying to figure it out, but this helps me quite a lot.

Comment: The period of the sequence is a bit tricky to find without OEIS...

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ denote the sequence $1^1 + \dotsm + n^n \pmod{10} $. Let $b_n = n^n \pmod{10}$.

First, I use computer to find that the period of the sequence $b_n = n^n \pmod{10}$. This gives a sequence with period $20$. Computing the period of this sequence is also possible by hand, but quite tedious, because you need to find the periods of $n^n$ for various $n$.

Now, $a_n$ is the partial sums of $b_n$, i.e. $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n b_n$. Note that we have $a_n = b_n + a_{n-1}$. There are $10$ possibilities of $a_{n-1}$. And $b_n$ is periodic with period $20$. So $a_n$ has period dividing $10 \times 20 = 200$.
Then, $a_{1234} = a_{34}$ and I think you can manually compute $a_{34}$.

I try to explain the part about why period divides 200:
Imagine we encode each term $a_n$ as a pair $(n \pmod{20}, a_{n-1})$. To reverse this encoding, from a pair $(k, a_j)$, we obtain the corresponding $a_n$ by $a_n = b_k + a_j$. The sequence of pairs follows the relationship: the pair after $(x, y)$ is $(x+1, y + b_x)$. Now, it is quite clear that the pairs are a valid encoding of the sequence $a_n$, in the sense that they capture correctly the recurrence relation:
$$ (x, y) \mapsto (x+1, y + b_x) $$
corresponds to
$$ (n-1, a_{n-2}) \mapsto (n, a_{n-2} + b_{n-1}) = (n, a_{n-1})$$

Now, there are only $10 \times 20$ possible pairs, which are
$$ \{ (k, j) : k = 1, ..., 20, \quad j = 0, ...,9 \}$$
So eventually, as we go along the sequence of pairs, we will start repeating pairs after 200 terms. Hence, the sequence has period dividing 200.

If this explanation is not clear, try to see the same reasoning applied to a different example here: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2015/08/04/last-digits-fibonacci-numbers/)